# Flutter: How to get the baseurl from the societies?

Tags: flutter, dart, base-url

for an authentication I would like to recover the base_url of the company chosen from a drop-down list, but I can't do it, being a beginner a little help will be welcome. 
here is the code of the dropdownlist:

```
class DropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  DropDown({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<DropDown> {
  String _mySelection;
  String _myBaseUrl;
  List<Map> _myJson = [{"id":2,"society":"test","baseUrl":"url.com"},{"id":1,"society":"planeef","baseUrl":"url.com"}];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: new DropdownButton<String>(
          isDense: true,
          hint: new Text("Select"),
          value: _mySelection,
          onChanged: (String newValue) {
            setState(() {
              _mySelection = newValue;
            });
          },
          items: _myJson.map((Map map) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: map["id"].toString(),
              child: new Text(
                map["society"],
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code below. You can use `singleWhere` function to retrieve the element from the `id` value you are getting from the dropdown and then read `baseUrl` from the element.

The `singleWhere` function matches and returns a single element from the list based on the condition we provide.

**Note -**
The `singleWhere` function throws an error by default if there are duplicates or no element is found. You might need to also pass the `orElse` parameter to `singleWhere` or add some error handling in that case.

More about that can be found [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Iterable/singleWhere.html).

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _mySelection;

  List<Map> _myJson = [{"id":2,"society":"test","baseUrl":"url.com"},{"id":1,"society":"planeef","baseUrl":"url.com"}];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: new DropdownButton<String>(
          isDense: true,
          hint: new Text("Select"),
          value: _mySelection,
          onChanged: (String newValue) {
             Map<dynamic,dynamic> _myElement = _myJson.singleWhere((test) => test["id"] == int.parse(newValue));
            print(_myElement["baseUrl"]);
            //Add the above two lines

            setState(() {
              _mySelection = newValue;
            });
          },
          items: _myJson.map((Map map) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: map["id"].toString(),
              child: new Text(
                map["society"],
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i had some small pixel problems but your solution works :)